# Angular2 - Unresolved Variables

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Complete noob looking for help,
I've been learning Angular2 and attempting to make a basic app but now its broken!

The component.ts file

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from './player.model';

@Component({
 selector : 'app-player',
 templateUrl : '/player.component.html'
})

export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  players: Player[] = [
  new Player('Malus', 'Lina', 'lol', 3000)
];

  constructor() {}
 ngOnInit() {}

}
```

model.ts

```
export class Player {
  public playerName: string;
  public favHero: string;
  public heroImage: string;
  public mmr: number;

  constructor( name: string, favHero: string, heroImage: string, mmr: number) {
    this.playerName = name;
    this.favHero = favHero;
    this.heroImage = heroImage;
    this.mmr =  mmr;
  }
}
```

lastly where the error is in the HTML

I am trying to use `{{ players.playerName }}` etc but they are unresolved? I think this is why my app is broken now

apparently, the variables of my array are unresolved?. I don't get it and cant work out why.
Appreciate any help thanks

Comment: you should learn how to post a question with proper formatting i just fixed you post with too many formatting errors , see here for help before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an object key of an array (`players.playerName)`, which you can't do. You either need to access a particular index `players[0].playerName` or loop through your players and create a DOM block for each player

```
<div *ngFor="let player of players">
    {{player.playerName}}
</div>
```

Comment: so i can't  do this ? <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix"
       *ngFor="let player of players">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> {{ players.playerName }}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"> {{ players.favHero }}</p>
      </div>

Comment: @AndrewLaurenson when you do `players.playerName` & `players.favHero` you are accessing the entire array. Within your ngFor block, you want to only access each iteration of the array, which you define `let player (<-- single iteration of players) of players`. So instead do `player.playerName` & `player.favHero`

Comment: OK i get it now, thanks!   Unfortunately i'm still getting problems compiling now, stupid old "aw snap" on chrome! no idea why its doing this now. Thanks though

Comment: @AndrewLaurenson that is usually caused by some issue outside of your app. (internet, cache, hanging process, etc.)

Comment: @AndrewLaurenson guess it could be an infinite loop

Comment: @AndrewLaurenson nothing stands out that would cause an error like that. You should only be getting a runtime error due to the `players.playerName` code.